# How to add groups to asp.net dropdownlist control?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have to implement groups in asp.net **dropdownlist.** 
eg: I have a classname as dropdownlist group and students in the class as its options.

How can I implement this using  ***JqueryUI Multiselect.***

Comment: Check http://ignatu.co.uk/articles/Adding_groups_to_the_ASPNET_DropDownList_control/

Comment: Thanks.. But its not using JqueryUI Multiselect. is there any simple solution @Aish

Comment: How about http://dotnetawesome.blogspot.in/2014/01/how-to-grouping-list-Items-option-in-aspnet-dropdownlist-control.html